# How to display an image if browser doesn't support HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, html5-canvas

I have some HTML 5 content with Javascript which generates a set of rectangles and texts with links. 
That code doesn't work on the IE8 because it doesn't support HTML 5. 
I want the browser to display an image instead of a text, if the page is shown in an IE8 or any other browser that doesn't support HTML5.

I tried this code but it didn't gave me the expected output.

```
  function draw(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  // check if supported
  if(canvas.getContext){

    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var ctz=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctz.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctz.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

    //..Rest of the code to add html5 content

    }else{
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = 'http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg';
    img.width = 276;
    img.height = 110;
    img.alt = '';

    document.body.appendChild(img);

    }
}
draw();
```

What could be the error here?

Comment: "Javascript which generates a set of rectangles and texts with links. " Why are you using canvas for this? Rectangles and texts/links are easier to do with plain old HTML than canvas.

Comment: I want to display a Hierarchical Graph with rectangles connected to each other with lines and texts inside them. Those texts would be links to other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of the [`canvas` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas), its content acts as fallback content: it is ignored by browsers that implement the element, but it will naturally be processed and displayed by older browsers that simply ignore the `<canvas ...>` and `</canvas>` tags. Example:

```
<canvas id=myCanvas>
<img src=http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg
     alt="" width=276 height=110>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this searlier but i think i placed the image tag outside the canvas tag.Thank you for the clear explanation also. :)